# Search the Registry key if the Registry Key delete through command Prompt

Tags: command-line

I want to search the Registry Key, if the registry key is exist it has to delete the Registry key through command Prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try using Powershell,
check out
http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/05/12/weekend-scripter-use-powershell-to-easily-modify-registry-property-values.aspx
I am sure that there are loads of other great examples good luck